# How to let script know that a GameObject is grabbed in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, steam

I am working on a VR project using SteamVR  and  I need specific event ( particle system ) to start when a GameObject is grabbed with the controllers
I tried this code (C#) to determine if this gameObject is grabbed and it didn't work properly(it appears like it's always true)

```
    private Interactable interactable;
    public bool isGrabbed=false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        interactable = this.GetComponent<Interactable>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (interactable != null )
        {

            isGrabbed = true;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
transform.GetComponent<OVRGrabbable>().isGrabbed
```

Comment: Please explain HOW your code snippet solves the OP's issue.

Comment: well... you just have to snap that code snippet into an if, and then on the body start the partycle system... srlsy mate... you can´t get lost xD

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if it's attached to a hand:

```
if (interactable != null && interactable.attachedToHand != null) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are checking here is if the Component `interactable` exist -> Checking if it is not `null`. Of course, if you did not delete it, it exists.

What you should probably be using is the provided `Throwable` class or one of the others. Have a look at the Demo Scene in the SteamVR/InteractionSystem Folder since it has been updated not too long ago and is now much more capable.

Depending on your needs you should check the Bow or whatever you find. There is also a Documentation pdf if the SteamVR Folder called "SteamVR Unity Plugin - Input System.pdf" which includes Documentation.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you .I saw this demo earlier and took this code from the grenade to not explode in the hand:
            if (interactable != null && interactable.attachedToHand != null) 
                return;